# How to change an ff vector to a normal vector R

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

I have a function that accepts vectors as inputs.

I have an `ffdf` named `X`, and would like to use columns of data as vectors for the function inputs.

To take a column of data named "Mag" as a vector I would use the following:

```
X[['Mag']]
```

However this is an `ff` vector I believe and the function will only accept a normal vector, how do I change this back to a normal vector?

I think I need to use just the physical components but I am not sure how to code this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `X[, 'Mag']` not work?

Comment: And did you try wrapping it in "as.vector"?

Comment: Quick look at `help('ff')` suggests the data are treated by `R` just like any other data.  What function are you feeding your `X[['Mag']]` to and what error message do you get?   What class is that data?

Comment: i tend to use as.ram(X$Mag)

Comment: I have used as.ram(X$Mag), this worked fine, however I then wanted to transfer the output 'vector' back into my ffdf, however when using the as.ffdf function, i get the following error:Error in ff(initdata = initdata, length = length, levels = levels, ordered = ordered,  : 
  bad argument initdata for existing file; initializing existing file is invalid. Interestingly using as.data.frame works fine so it does not make much sense, any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear on what you are doing but you can not add a vector to and ffdf, you can add an ff vector to an ffdf. So X$mynewcolumn <- as.ff(myfunctionwhichIexecute(as.ram(X$Mag))) will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `[]` at the end.

```
X <- as.ffdf(data.frame(Mag = 1:10))
class(X[["Mag"]])      # ff_vector" "ff" 
class(X[["Mag"]][])    # "integer"

# X[, 'Mag'] also works as jbaums suggested
class(X[, 'Mag'])

# as.vector doesn't work
class(as.vector(X[["Mag"]])) # ff_vector" "ff"
```